# Como insertar en la base de datos varios registros obtenidos en un array de arrays desde el Request de Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, array

Me encuentro haciendo un crud en laravel y mi intención es ingresar varios registros a la vez en la base de datos, pero al parecer se debe a la forma en como llegan a mi request del controlador que no me esta permitiendo.

Los datos desde el formulario los envió añadiendo la llave [] a cada campo y como request obtengo esto:

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {
    #parameters: array:4 [
      "_token" => ""
      "alimento_id" => array:2 [
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
      ]
      "valor" => array:2 [
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
      ]
      "nombre" => array:2 [
        0 => "a"
        1 => "b"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

pero no se cual es la forma correcta de obtener una estructura así:

```
['alimento_id'=>1, 'valor'=>1 , 'nombre'=>a],
['alimento_id'=>2, 'valor'=>2 , 'nombre'=>b]
```

y posteriormente mediante un foreach crearlos en la base:

```
foreach($request as  $r){
    Dieta::create($r);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede que la creación del formulario no sea la más adecuada para este caso de uso, quizá es más conveniente crear una estructura de objetos por el lado del cliente y luego enviarla a tu controlador para asegurarte que las propiedades corresponden a cada objeto.

Revisa el uso de [arreglos en html para php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) e intenta crear objetos únicos.

**¿Por qué lo anterior?**

Para este ejemplo, estoy asumiendo que siempre llega la misma cantidad de valores para cada clave, pero si no es el caso, aparte de obtener una linda excepción, los registros que se inserten no serán íntegros ya que los valores de sus propiedades estarán al "azar".

De todas formas, si ya cubriste el apartado anterior y solo necesitas ordenar los valores para insertarlos, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php



$data = [
    "alimento_id" => [0 => "1", 1 => "2"],
    "valor" => [0 => "1", 1 => "2"],
    "nombre" => [0 => "a", 1 => "b" ]
];


$elements = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($data['alimento_id']); $i++){
    $row = array();
    $row['alimento_id'] = $data['alimento_id'][$i];
    $row['valor'] = $data['valor'][$i];
    $row['nombre'] = $data['nombre'][$i];
    array_push($elements, $row);
}


foreach($elements as $element){
    print_r($element);
    // Here use $element for create your object
}
```